# ¿Como puedo convertir un mensaje string a código ascii y de este ultimo a código binario? En pycharm

Tags: python, bucles, binario

He intentado y me quedo estancada aquí:
No entiendo como hacer que los códigos binarios de cada letrita estén en una misma linea.

```py
class Solution:
    """String -> ASCII -> binary"""
    def transform(self, stringToTransform):
        oracion=stringToTransform
        for letra in oracion:
            asc= ord(letra)
            binario= format(asc,"08b")
            print(binario)

        return oracion


stringToTransform = "hola como estas"
print(Solution().transform(stringToTransform))
```

Comment: el problema es que haces el print dentro del for. Para solucionarlo concatena el resultado dentro del for y despues haz el print

Comment: hola, no comprendo muy bien soy nueva en esto, podrias indicarme en un codigo porfavor?

Comment: lo del compi de abajo (Candid Moe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es guardar las representaciones binarias en una lista hasta tenerlas todas.

Una vez completa la lista, usas `join` para unir las partes en un solo string.

```
class Solution:
    """String -> ASCII -> binary"""
    def transform(self, stringToTransform):
        resultado = []
        for letra in stringToTransform:
            asc= ord(letra)
            binario= format(asc,"08b")
            resultado.append(binario)

        return " ".join(resultado)
```

Lo que produce:

```
01101000 01101111 01101100 01100001 00100000 01100011 01101111 01101101 01101111 00100000 01100101 01110011 01110100 01100001 01110011
```

Nota:

Todo el procedimiento se puede acortar a:

```
def transform(self, stringToTransform):
    return " ".join([format(ord(letra), "08b") for letra in stringToTransform])
```